# Bootstrap div as table td, middle text

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

problem with set vertical align to content inside div
Example:

```
<div class="row border">
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1">
  <span class="align-middle">Short</span>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1 ">
  <span class="align-middle">Long col with long text</span>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/lymychm/cuv10dqo/

I want to vertically show text in div's.

So if i set line-height to `span` it works, but when text has many words with spaces between them...each word now starts from new line and this line(each) has same line-height

Example: 
https://jsfiddle.net/lymychm/prc2rstd/

This is what i want, but on `div` https://jsfiddle.net/lymychm/zn48z0ex/

Comment: Check the answer below, hope that is what you wanted. :)

Answer (score 1):

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.line-height-class {
  line-height: 120px;
}
.abc { display: table;
    width: 100px; /* width of parent */
    height:100px; /* height of parent */
    overflow: hidden; }
.inner {
     display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="row border">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1 abc">
      <span class="align-middle inner">Short</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1 ">
      <span class="align-middle">Long col with long text</span>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox, See the example: https://jsfiddle.net/prc2rstd/6/

HTML,

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="row align-middle">
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1 column">
        <span>Short</span>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1 column">
        <span>Long col with long text</span>
      </div>   
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS,

```
.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.align-middle {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.column {
  width: 70px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As when float :left is used then it is hard to make it vertically align middle. we need to define row as a table and its inner div as table cell and remove floats from it. But somehow we have another good approach for it i.e using `flexbox`, demo `https://jsfiddle.net/anmolsandal/cuv10dqo/1/`

Updated css

```
.border {
 border: 1px solid red;
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
}

.line-height-class {
  line-height: 120px;
}
```

code

```
 <div class="row border">
   <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1">
     <span class="align-middle">Short</span>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1 ">
     <span class="align-middle">Long col with long text</span>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code in your css,

```
.col-lg-1 {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    float: none;
}
```

change that class name...

Answer (score 0):

Expand the width of your div like [this fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/prc2rstd/1/)

```css
.border {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.line-height-class {
  line-height: 120px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row border">
    <div class="col-lg-1 col-md-1 col-xs-1 col-sm-1">
      <span class="align-middle line-height-class">Short</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-xs-9 col-sm-9 ">
      <span class="align-middle line-height-class">Long col with long text</span>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: ok, this is funny, but i put col-..-1 instead of col-..-9 not because i like number 1, i have another 10 divs with col-..-1 after second div, so i need behaviour for long long text, this text can be as long as more then col-..-9 cols, so what then? buy new monitor with bigger screen?)